# how to revoke CREATE privilege on public schema from specific user?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am currently trying to create a new read-only user in Amazon Redshift.

The Redshift version I am using is:

```
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 
    (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.735
```

After creating the read-only user, I need to be able to restrict the `CREATE` privilege on `PUBLIC SCHEMA` for only that particular user (but not for the rest of the users!).

Using the following command, I am able to revoke `CREATE` access from all users of the database cluster. However, that's not something I want to do. What I need is to retain the `CREATE` privileges on all users except for the ones that I am going to restrict explicitly.

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has no `DENY` ACLs. So you can't grant to all, then revoke from one.

You must instead revoke the right from public, create a new role, grant it to that role, and grant all the users who should have the desired access `inherit` membership of the new role, leaving the one who should not have access out of the role.

This may be true for Redshift too, I don't know for sure and Amazon don't offer any free public test instances.